# Enable CORS in springboot mail API

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, nginx

I have easy mail sending springboot API and reactjs app for fetch.
Hosted in nginx server. 
React app running well localhost, email working everything okei but if I run on a server it gives an error.

I have tried to add different Nginx server settings and add Springboot 
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/")` but have not found any help so far.
Where do I have to allow CORS if I deploy to server?

**Nginx server default:**

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   root /var/www/name/build;
   server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location /  {
    }
}
```

**Springboot:**

```
@PostMapping
public void sendFeedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback,
                         BindingResult bindingResult){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        throw new ValidationException("Feedback is not valid");
    }

    // Create a mail sender
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    mailSender.setHost(this.emailCfg.getHost());
    mailSender.setPort(this.emailCfg.getPort());
    mailSender.setUsername(this.emailCfg.getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(this.emailCfg.getPassword());

    // Create an email instance
    SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mailMessage.setFrom(feedback.getEmail());
    mailMessage.setTo("test@gmail.com");
    mailMessage.setSubject("Testing mail");
    mailMessage.setText(feedback.getFeedback());
    mailSender.send(mailMessage);
}
```

**Reactjs code I have:**

```
fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(state)
}).then(response =>{
    console.log(data)
}).catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
})
```

**Output:**

```
Access to fetch at 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/feedback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' from 
origin 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a CORS config as below :

## CORSConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD");
    }
}
```

OR 
Annonate your controller

```
@CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping
    public void sendFeedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback,
            BindingResult bindingResult){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            throw new ValidationException("Feedback is not valid");
        }

        // Create a mail sender
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        mailSender.setHost(this.emailCfg.getHost());
        mailSender.setPort(this.emailCfg.getPort());
        mailSender.setUsername(this.emailCfg.getUsername());
        mailSender.setPassword(this.emailCfg.getPassword());

        // Create an email instance
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setFrom(feedback.getEmail());
        mailMessage.setTo("test@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setSubject("Testing mail");
        mailMessage.setText(feedback.getFeedback());
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was missing  OPTIONS.
`@RequestMapping(value = "/feedback", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)`

Comment: You should not use method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS . It should either POST/GET, the OPTIONS is an internal call from ajax whenever it is delegating some request to other resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your server not responding with the proper headers.  If you look at your network tab you will see and `OPTIONS` request that fires before your `POST` request.  Your server needs to respond to that `OPTIONS` request to let the browser know its ok for the requesting client to access the resource. You can read more about it [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) but at the very least your server should respond to the preflight with headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example <== your domain here
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:9000")
@GetMapping("/hello")
public Greeting greeting() {
    return "world";
}
```

or

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:9000", maxAge=3600)
@RestController
public class RestController {}
```