# "cors header ‘access-control-allow-origin’ missing" denies request, even though origin is allowed

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to a send POST request from my angular app to my server (written with spring-boot). The request gets denied with the message "cors header ‘access-control-allow-origin’ missing".

I enabled the origin of my angular app "http://localhost:4200" like I did for my other RestControllers (Which work). The only difference as far as I can tell is that I handel POST requests in my not working controller.

#### Controller

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ReqRepository reqRepository;

    @PostMapping("/reqs")
    public Req saveReq (@Valid @RequestBody Req req) {
        return reqRepository.save(req);
    }
}
```

#### Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface ReqRepository extends JpaRepository<Req, Long> {
}
```

#### Angular Service

```js
@Injectable()
export class ReqService {

  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendReq(req: Req): Observable<Req> {
    return this.http.post<Req>('http://localhost:8080/reqs', req, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

I thought allowing the origin would be enough so the request is possible but it get's blocked. It seems like I am missing something to enable POST requests.

#### Update

I further tested the controller and it works for GET requests.
I just change the the method, so it seems like the problem lies in the POST request.
Below ist the controller with a GET test endpoint instead of a POST endpoint

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ReqRepository reqRepository;

    @GetMapping("/reqs")
    public Page<Req> testCall (Pageable pageable) {
        System.out.println("Geeting request");
        return reqRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

Comment: you allow localhost but send `*` ...

Comment: It can be solved by adding cors config [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289162/403-error-for-cors-preflight-options-request-how-to-fix/56289441#56289441)

Comment: @trichetriche I changed the wildcard * to "http://localhost:4200" but it still doesnt work

Comment: @lm1010 shouldn't the CrossOrigin annotion work? I think all a config would do is to enable cors for the whole application, so I don't have to do it in every controller

Comment: @lm1010 creating a cors config like in the link you provides leads to a Http 403 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my spring security configuration.
I had to disable csrf because it is enabled by default.
I got the solution from this post: [How to Solve 403 Error in Spring Boot Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486314/how-to-solve-403-error-in-spring-boot-post-request/50491615)

My solution looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //Override basic security settings so no login page is needed to access the RestEndpoints
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
        security.httpBasic().disable();
        security.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad that your request is working now. Please note `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` is a header sent from the server. Here you are trying to send the header from angular to server which will not work

Also please change `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`

to `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", methods="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,ORIGIN")` and see if it works

Comment: Hey, sadly the request is not working. Only a GET Request is working at the moment but I need a POST request. But everytime I do a POST request I get a cors error

Comment: @GhostMST, I have updated the answer, please give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I specified POST as an allowed Request methode but I still get the same error. `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", methods= RequestMethod.POST)` As far as I understand if I don't specify RequestMethods all methods are allowed by default. What's interesting is that if I use a global config like @lm1010 linked aboce I get no cors error but a 403 Access denied error.