# Spring Boot- Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot.  I am trying to use the save() functionality via the JPA library using Postman for the first time.  My database is a legacy Mysql database.  Generically speaking, this table contains data of baseball players who have been drafted into a fantasy baseball league.  The primary key of my table is 'play_id', and I also track the player's 'mlb_id' (Major League Baseball's unique identifier) in the same table.

Here is my code:

Table setup in Mysql:

```
 CREATE TABLE `mlb_rosters` (
  `play_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `mlb_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name_first` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_last` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  `bats` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `throws` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `mlb_rosters`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`play_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `mlb_id` (`mlb_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `mlb_id_2` (`mlb_id`);

ALTER TABLE `mlb_rosters`
  MODIFY `play_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6730;
```

I also ran insert statements for approximately ~1500 players, so this is not a blank table.

My object in Springboot:

```
package com.example.demo.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="mlb_rosters")
public class IbcMlbPlayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="play_id", columnDefinition = "int(10)")
    private Integer playId;

    @Column(name="mlb_id")
    private Integer mlbId;

    @Column(name="name_first", columnDefinition = "varbinary(255)")
    private String nameFirst;

    @Column(name="name_last", columnDefinition = "varbinary(255)")
    private String nameLast;

    @Column(name="bats")
    private String bats;

    @Column(name="throws")
    private String thrws;

    @Column(name="birthday")
    private String birthday;

    public IbcMlbPlayer(){

    }

    public Integer getPlayId() {
        return playId;
    }

    public void setPlayId(Integer playId) {
        this.playId = playId;
    }

    public Integer getMlbId() {
        return mlbId;
    }

    public void setMlbId(Integer mlbId) {
        this.mlbId = mlbId;
    }

    public String getNameFirst() {
        return nameFirst;
    }

    public void setNameFirst(String nameFirst) {
        this.nameFirst = nameFirst;
    }

    public String getNameLast() {
        return nameLast;
    }

    public void setNameLast(String nameLast) {
        this.nameLast = nameLast;
    }

    public String getBats() {
        return bats;
    }

    public void setBats(String bats) {
        this.bats = bats;
    }

    public String getThrws() {
        return thrws;
    }

    public void setThrws(String thrws) {
        this.thrws = thrws;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

The relevant path of my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveIbcMlbPlayer")
    public IbcMlbPlayer saveIbcMlbPlayer(@RequestBody IbcMlbPlayer ibcMlbPlayer){
        return ibcMlbPlayerDao.save(ibcMlbPlayer);
    }
```

My Dao:

```
package com.example.demo.dao;

import com.example.demo.entities.IbcMlbPlayer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IbcMlbPlayerDao extends JpaRepository<IbcMlbPlayer, Integer> {
}
```

When I attempt to do a Post request to the save path and pass in the JSON object of the player who I'm attempting to create, I get the following error:

Duplicate entry '25' for key 'PRIMARY'

In this case, I've tried this 25 times, so Postman/Spring Boot keep incrementing the 'play_id' field by 1 (this number goes up in the error message by one each time I test).

I understand the error, for whatever reason, Spring Boot isn't getting the max value of the 'play_id' field, incrementing it by one, and then attempting to do the insert.  I would have expected 'play_id' to be 6730, which I believe is the table's max play_id plus one.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUTO shouldn't be used as GenerationType you must use IDENTITY

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="play_id", columnDefinition = "int(10)")
private Integer playId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I test this in Postman, I get 403 Forbidden, Invalid CORS request.  I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Is this a new problem? If yes please ask a separate question

Comment: I guess that depends on how you look at it.  It's hard to tell if flipping to GenerationType.IDENTITY fixed the issue or not.  It's a different result, so I suppose we're evolving.

Comment: how does your security configuratoin look like?

Comment: I fixed it.  I copied the CorsConfig from this thread and now it works.  You gave the correct answer.  Thank you very much!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289162/403-error-for-cors-preflight-options-request-how-to-fix/56289703

Comment: "cannot find symbol class GeneratedValue" . any clue to this issue?

Comment: Have you imported the Annotation and jpa in the classpath?

Comment: I'm working on spring boot webflux application. it didn't allow me to import that annotation. try adding below to pom.xml but not supported.
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: you should ask your own question. Please don't ask questions in comments

Comment: Using `AUTO` on `GenerationType' will cause an error at times especially f this id column is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your database. An `AUTO_INCREMENT` value should be unique, but in some cases `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` may give a value for insertion which may already be present in a table.